# User gets error number 18456 while trying to connect to Azure SQL database

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

There are many threads about this error but I did not find the answer yet.
We have Azure SQL database and the employees use 1 login to connect.
One colleague has problem with aonnectivity as recently her Azure account was deleted and then restored.
The account deletion may have triggered the issue.

> Error Number: 18456
> Severity: 14
> State: 1
> Line Number: 65536

Do you have any ideas what causes this error?
Any hints where I should dig to get an answer?

Comment: Posting the actual error, and whatever is on line 65536 would really help us help you.

Comment: According to the documentation, [MSSQLSERVER_18456](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error?view=sql-server-ver15), you have a login error. Consult the Server's logs to get the real error, and debug from there.

Comment: How do you connect? Via code, SSMS? If the account was deleted, did you check the newly created account has permissions to access the database?

Comment: We use SSMS. One login is used by many employees but only 1 colleague cannot access. Do we need to check the login/user account settings in SQL Server or permissions should be checked in Azure Portal?

Answer (score 0):

I have found Error 18456 with State 1 only during Microsoft Azure outages as shown [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/216708/azure-sql-server-database-error-18456-severity-14-state-1). To make sure visit [@AzureSupport](https://twitter.com/AzureSupport) on Twitter or visit [Azure Status](https://status.azure.com/en-us/status). Sometimes Azure Support and Azure Status do not show any issues because issues may not be affecting a good number of customers, but you can still find out what is happening by going to Help + Support, choose Service Health, then examine "Health History" and "Resource Health" as shown on [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/resource-health-exposes-historical-health/?wt.mc_id=MVP) article.

Another possible cause of this error is the status of your Azure Subscription. Maybe your subscription requires your attention.

Comment: I am not sure if this is the right path. I have 2 developers who constantly work on this database and they did not report any connectivity issues. Only the user who got her Azure AD account deleted and restored.

They use SQL Server Authentication as authentication method and they provide the same login.

Comment: Did you examine the Resource Health section, on the left vertical panel of the Azure SQL Database (Azure Portal)? Please examine that first? Any scale up/down of the database tier? AD logins get disconected while scale operations are in progress.Contained logins do not get disconected.